# List<String> as input of GET method

Tags: java, string, list, jersey

I have a REST service. The input type of the GET method is `List<String>`:

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<myObject> getData(List<String> IDs) {
    ....
}
```

I tried to test this method using curl. I used a lot of different combinations of data:

```
curl -X GET --data-binary '{"IDs":["TestString1","TestString2"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/myModule/rs/getData -v
                          '{"TestString1","TestString2"}'
                          '["TestString1","TestString2"]'
                           so on
```

But I always get the response:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
or
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
```

Is it possible to have the input as `List<String>`? Are my curl requests incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're [sending a POST request](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary):

> --data-binary < data>
>
> (HTTP)  This  **posts** data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.

Since [`-X` sets a custom request type](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X), I'm guessing it's not detecting that it needs to URL encode the data:

> -X, --request < command>
>
> (HTTP) Specifies a **custom request method** to use when communicating with the HTTP server. The specified request will be used instead of the method otherwise used (which defaults to GET). Read the HTTP 1.1 specification for details and explanations. Common additional HTTP requests include PUT and DELETE, but related technologies like WebDAV offers PROPFIND, COPY, MOVE and more.

So try with [`-G`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) instead:

> -G, --get
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with -d, --data or --data-binary to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

Comment: no, curl don't want to work. With --data-binary method param is always empty .... (( Thank you - you helped me to find the bug

Comment: @VictorMezrin It was empty because you were making a POST request and the method expected GET, so Jersey was ignoring the POST data.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :)

Method signature should be

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<myObject> getData(@QueryParam("myParamName") List<String> IDs) {
    ....
}
```

curl request

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/myModule/rs/getData?myParamName={dfsf,ddsfdss,sdfsf} -v
```

it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourUrl?param1=value1&param1=value2
```

This will convert to

```
List<string>param1 = [...]
```

you get the point